# my project in visual studio c# only respnds to D and not the other keys

Tags: c#

the code below is meant to detect when the player presses a key (a s or d) but it only responds to d and I can't figure out why. I'm pretty new to coding and this is for a school project in visual studio c# 
p1 to 3 detects what character you're using and when you press a button it makes the idle animation stop( called auto) you cna only attack when your energy is full

```
  private void FrmFinalProject_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (p1 == 2)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
            {
                if (p1Energy >= 10)
                {


                    tmrBatAtk2.Enabled = true;

                    picBatAuto.Visible = false;
                    picBatAtk2.Visible = true;
                    p1Energy = 0;
                    prgP1Bar.Value = 0;
                    pgrHpP2.Value = pgrHpP2.Value - 25;
                }
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
                {
                    if (p1Energy >= 10)
                    {


                        tmrBatAtk2.Enabled = true;

                        picBatAuto.Visible = false;
                        picBatAtk1.Visible = true;
                        p1Energy = 0;
                        prgP1Bar.Value = 0;
                        pgrHpP2.Value = pgrHpP2.Value - 30;
                    }



                }
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
                {
                    if (p1Energy >= 10)
                    {


                        tmrBatAtk2.Enabled = true;

                        picBatAuto.Visible = false;
                        picBatAtk3.Visible = true;
                        p1Energy = 0;
                        prgP1Bar.Value = 0;
                        pgrHpP2.Value = pgrHpP2.Value - 35;
                    }



                }
            }
        }
        if (p1 == 1)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
            {
                if (p1Energy >= 10)
                {


                    tmrFriendAtk.Enabled = true;

                    PicFriendAuto.Visible = false;
                    picFriendAtk1.Visible = true;
                    p1Energy = 0;
                    prgP1Bar.Value = 0;
                    pgrHpP2.Value = pgrHpP2.Value - 25;
                }
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
                {
                    if (p1Energy >= 10)
                    {


                        tmrFriendAtk.Enabled = true;

                        PicFriendAuto.Visible = false;
                        PicFriendAtk2.Visible = true;
                        p1Energy = 0;
                        prgP1Bar.Value = 0;
                        pgrHpP2.Value = pgrHpP2.Value - 30;
                    }



                }
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
                {
                    if (p1Energy >= 10)
                    {


                        tmrFriendAtk.Enabled = true;

                        PicFriendAuto.Visible = false;
                        picFriendatk3.Visible = true;
                        p1Energy = 0;
                        prgP1Bar.Value = 0;
                        pgrHpP2.Value = pgrHpP2.Value - 35;
                    }



                }
            }
        }
        if (p1 == 3)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
            {
                if (p1Energy >= 10)
                {


                    tmrKnightAtk.Enabled = true;

                    picKnightAuto.Visible = false;
                    knightatk1.Visible = true;
                    p1Energy = 0;
                    prgP1Bar.Value = 0;
                    pgrHpP2.Value = pgrHpP2.Value - 25;
                }
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
                {
                    if (p1Energy >= 10)
                    {


                        tmrKnightAtk.Enabled = true;

                        picKnightAuto.Visible = false;
                        knightAtk2.Visible = true;
                        p1Energy = 0;
                        prgP1Bar.Value = 0;
                        pgrHpP2.Value = pgrHpP2.Value - 30;
                    }



                }
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
                {
                    if (p1Energy >= 10)
                    {


                        tmrKnightAtk.Enabled = true;

                        picKnightAuto.Visible = false;
                        knightAtk3.Visible = true;
                        p1Energy = 0;
                        prgP1Bar.Value = 0;
                        pgrHpP2.Value = pgrHpP2.Value - 35;
                    }



                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Well, the code `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)` is within the `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)`..

Comment: If I may, I'd like to suggest revising the code to avoid so much indentation. which leads to issues like this. Perhaps move each player's actions to a method, and within those methods - as only one key can be pressed at once - once you've processed the key, `return` from the method. That makes your code more readable, and may get you a better grade :)

Comment: Once you've done that, you can look at each bit of code - are there code fragments that are repeated, which could themselves be methods? And it looks like you only take action `if (p1Energy >= 10)` - so `if (p1Energy < 10)` it doesn't matter what key you press, so you could check for that once before even looking at the key press.

Comment: You can solve this, and many other, problems by [using a debugger](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).

Comment: Helpful tip. Collapse methods. CTRL + M + O combination to collapse all methods and have a better picture of all the nested methods inside some others. The first IF statement always says IF == key is D. There's no ELSE for when it's another key. So basically the code is saying, IF key is D, and THEN if key is S which may never happen on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by others in the comments, the problem is your bracketing for the `IF` statements.  If you want to check the same thing, here a KeyPress, then it needs to be on the same level.  Look at the image where I have added a green line and red line to show statements on the same level.

[image: If Statement brakcets]

Your check for the keypress should all be on the green line, like the first one is, but the rest are not.

So to solve your problem you need to place an additional closing `}` bracket after your inner `if` statement (and do this for every one)

But the reason why you have this problem is because your code is too complex, so that when you have a bug like this it is difficult to find because it is difficult to read.   You also repeat the same check in multiple places (`p1Energy >= 10`) when you only need this once.

So you need to refactor your code.  Using switch statements and sub-methods means that you can better read your code, find bugs, and understand what is going on.

```
private void FrmFinalProject_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    int p1 = 2, p1Energy = 1;

    //if p1Energy >= 10 needs to be checked for every case, so we just check once at the beginning
    if (p1Energy >= 10)
    {
        //Now we use a switch to check the value of p1, and call sub-methods to perform the code
        switch (p1)
        {
            case 1:      Process1(e);
                 break;
            case 2:      Process2(e);
                 break;
            case 3:      Process3(e);
                  break;
         }
   }
```

So now you call a sub-method Process1/2/3() for each case.  Which would look something like this:

```
private void Process2(KeyEventArgs e)
 {
        switch(e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.D:   Process_2_D();
                break;
            case Keys.A:   Process_2_A();
                break;
            case Keys.S:   Process_2_S();
                break;
        }
    }
```

(Repeat for each case)

This then calls a sub-method for each sub-case which could look something like this

private void Process_2_D()
        {
            tmrBatAtk2.Enabled = true;
            picBatAuto.Visible = false;
            picBatAtk2.Visible = true;
            p1Energy = 0;
            prgP1Bar.Value = 0;
            pgrHpP2.Value = pgrHpP2.Value - 25;
        }
(Repeat for each case)

Although I would not say that this is brilliant code, it is now easier to read, and more importantly, much easier to debug.

This code can probably be improved significantly to be more effective.  But not knowing your program in detail then it is difficult to suggest more.  Plus, as you are a beginner this is probably enough.  And as this is a school project, then you first need to learn and if you turn up with amazing code then it will be clear that you have not coded it!!

At the end of the day, although you can spend a lot of time engineering a beautiful system, the end result may not be worth the effort in every case, especially for private projects where you are probably the only person working on this and will never or hardly ever change it.